# Dependent functions: eval or autoload?

Tags: autoload

I have a situation where I have a function that depends on other functions. So

```
(defun a ()
   (something))
```

and

```
(defun b ()
   (something-else))
```

are used by

```
(defun c ()
   (something-calling (a) (b))
```

Not wanting to do a blanket load of everything -- and not really wanting to rewrite to include `a` and `b` in a `cl-flet` block -- would I change `c` to use `eval`, or is there any trick to have `c` autoload what it is dependent upon? I've seen `autoload`, but I'm not sure if it's applicable here.

I guess I'd like to be able to talk to the elisp "live namespace" and tell it, "If you see *this* function called, go ahead and load/initialize *these* dependent functions/variables."

Answer (score 4):

You don't need autoload here. Just put `(require 'a-lib)` and `(require 'b-lib)` inside function `c` itself (assuming `a-lib` and `b-lib` are the libraries that define functions `a` and `b`, respectively).

That is, let function `c` load the libraries its code needs. They will be loaded only the first time (and only if they have not already been loaded).

```
(defun c ()
  (require 'a-lib)
  (require 'b-lib)
  (something-calling (a) (b))
```

Comment: Yes, `require` would be good, but what if `a` and `b` are not in the same file? I want them to be anywhere. Could I do some sort of path or net location? Again, I don't want to always be doing `require` on a whole "package" and I don't want to have to break down things to one function per file, either. Library of Babel allowed that, only very primitively.

Comment: The example I gave does not assume they are in the same file. It assumes what it says: that `a` is in file `a-lib.el` and `b` is in file `b-lib.el`. If you have no idea where they are then all you can do is punt. You either have the necessary libraries in your `load-path` or you tell Emacs to load them, one way or another. Even an autoload specifies which library defines a given function.

Comment: So yeah, if I don't do literally one function per file, I can't really call just one individual function. Again LOB is the only way for this in the Emacs elisp world. How about aliasing? Can I have a function actually somewhere else, but have a "stub" in the buffer I'm using (like CORBA)? Update: I just found corba.el. I'll take a look. . . .

Comment: @147pm You're over-engineering, imho.

Comment: @lunaryorn Ha! Maybe so. But I just don't like the globbiness of code. I want it to be airy. For example, I write a Package-A, but I want to write a Package-B that uses some subset of Package-A. Now it only seems like I can manually "copy" into Package-B what I need, or I can `require 'Package-A`. That seems clumsy and globby. I'd like a registry of functions and data where I can just go shopping and plug things (e.g. functions) together like lego blocks. BTW, I don't think I invented this idea.

Comment: You can also *autload* what you require, which was part of your original question, but that question is unclear in this regard. Autoloading loads a complete file. And that file might itself load others that it needs. There is no autoloading of only pieces of a file. Still, you can add `(autoload...)` sexps to your code to ensure that the files it requires are loaded.